# Detect if crosshair is pointing at object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my FPS, I'm looking for a way to detect if my crosshair is "looking" at a target. More specifically, when the center of the screen is touching the object. Basically, this means that if you would shoot, you would hit the target (zero spread).

I know this could be done using a raycaster, but that would mean I would constantly need to cast a ray (not only when shooting), which I think would take a lot of resources.

Is there another way? I've thought about using:

```
void OnMouseOver()
```

but the problem is that the mouse is not necessarily at the center of the screen, so it's not perfectly aligned with the center of my crosshair.

Any thoughts?

Comment: _"which I think would take a lot of resources"_ - have you tried it?

Comment: You *"think"* it would take too much resources? Or you know for sure? Because Raycasting is probably a lot less expensive than you think

Comment: If you specify layers and have a sensible max distance it's a very low cost for raycasts, we use raycasts for our laser sights in our game, no problem and player can put on up to for on a single rifle :)

Comment: By the way, `OnMouseOver` quite likely also uses raycasts (based on the fact that it does not detect objects on the "Ignore Raycast layer")

Comment: Three things:
First, as everyone else said, raycasting is really efficient and I think you should definitely use that.
Second, why would you "constantly need to cast a ray" when you can just cast when the fire function is triggered?
Third, it is common practice to cast a ray forward on every frame (for example, to detect loots on the floor) so don't feel bad doing it.

Comment: OK, I'll try raycasting, but I'm new to Unity :). I need a constant ray because I want to change the crosshair color when you're hovering the target with the crosshair (not shooting).
`void FixedUpdate()
 {
  Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
  if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10000))
   print("There is something in front of the object!");
 }`
from the docs is not working... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm getting there. Didn't know the existence of Debug.DrawRay, which is really helpful when new to raycasting. Thanks!

Comment: For a "constant stream" you want to do your ray in Update() instead of FixedUpdate. Update() is run every frame while FixedUpdate() is run 60 times per second and isn't connected to the frames. A "constant stream" means doing something every frame, from a user perspective.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I've managed to achieve what I was looking for.